# Junit- How to attach test to an existing process

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have maven project, and running running `mvn test` executes test cases within a separate process.

My ask is: Is there any way to run tests by attaching to an existing process?
So that tests can use the attached process environment.

I found surefire has `JVM`property, [found here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#jvm), but could not get how to set it, if this is correct understanding.

**Update:**
As the project is SpringBoot based, so i executed server (Say it test server) like this-

```
java -jar target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And updated Junit test classes like this-

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    VirtualMachine virtualMachine = attach(getTestServerVM());
    System.out.println(virtualMachine.id());
}

@Test
public void emptyTest() {
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    assertTrue(stack.isEmpty());
}

private static VirtualMachine attach(VirtualMachineDescriptor virtualMachineDescriptor) {

    VirtualMachine virtualMachine = null;

    try {
        virtualMachine = VirtualMachine.attach(virtualMachineDescriptor);

    } catch (AttachNotSupportedException anse) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't attach " + anse);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Exception attaching or reading a jvm." + ioe);
    } 

    return virtualMachine;
}

private static VirtualMachineDescriptor getTestServerVM() {

    String name = "target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar";
    List<VirtualMachineDescriptor> vms = VirtualMachine.list();

    VirtualMachineDescriptor serverVM = vms.stream()
              .filter(vm -> name.equals(vm.displayName()))
              .findAny()
              .orElse(null);

    System.out.println("Test server id : " + serverVM.id());

    return serverVM;
}
```

Is this suffice or do i need to load the agent?
I am asking this, because though program shows that Junit test class attached successfully, i see process id for Junit like this (by running `JCMD` command)-

```
3585 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3 -port 55632 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames JunitRnD.J
```

Answer (score 2):

In the end, you are asking: how can I *inject* arbitrary code into a *running* JVM.

Probably this is technically doable; but would require a lot of work; and probably dirty hacking. To gain ... what?

Long story short: I think you should step back, and carefully look in the "why" you want to do that. And then strive for another solution!

Given your comment: good unit tests should focus on **small** units. If you need your "whole stack" to be up and running; then don't call them unit tests; because they aren't. They are functional/integration tests!

When you really want to look into **unit tests**; then learn about mocking frameworks ... and probably: how to **testable** code. These [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) here a great start into that topic.

Seriously: attaching to a JVM to run unit tests is not a good answer. Instead, step back; and look into your design; and find ways to test it on "smaller" scope.

Another update on your 2nd comment: if you really need such a level of "dynamics"; then I would suggest something completely different: integrate [Jython](http://www.jython.org/index.html) into your product; at least for your "development" setup. That will allow you to send **jython** scripts (python code that can call **all** use all your java classes) into the JVM.

But again: look into writing real unit tests; **any** application can benefit from that. I have coworkers who always tell me that they need to run "functional tests" when debugging problems. Me, I am working on the same software stack; I typically need log files; and then I adapt my **unit tests** to repro the issue; I only need "system time" very late in the game to do a final test of the fix before that goes into the field.

But just for the record: we have jython in our development systems, too. And yes, that is **great** to even have a "shell" running in your JVM.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The reason is: Test cases are heavily depend on environment setup, for each test i don't want to waste time for setup and configuration, rather focusing on problem to solve by unit tests.

Comment: May be i dont have to say "unit test" rather just test. And reason for test to be heavily depend on environment setup is due to nature of application that it relies several different component. Lets say app has problem in production, to solve that, created same environment on my local or stage environment, and now want to execute my tests to see what is breaking. For this i just need to setup environment once. Hope this clarifies my need.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt helps and suggestion. As i said earlier, tests are not just unit, but integration and functional as well. I am thinking of attaching tests with test environment JVM with help of VirtualMachine API's. Any other idea?

Comment: can you please provide sample for Jython script to be used?

Comment: I am not familiar with how it is "integrated". I just know that I can call a certain tool on our systems; and that will open a jython shell **within** the one JVM that runs our system. Or I can pipe a script into that command. Imagine it like starting a python interpreter - but that it runs within a JVM; and it allows you to write "python" code to deal with **all** your java belongings.